# Git- Why .txt file is not ignored

Tags: git, ignore

I need to ignore .txt file in git. To do so i have included *.txt in the .gitignore file.But when i edit something in one of my .txt 
file git is still tracking it. Where is the problem or do i make something wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Was the file already tracked by git before it was added to the .gitignore?  Git will continue to track anything _explicitly_ being tracked already.

Comment: Could you post your .gitignore, please?

Answer (score 30):

If you've ever committed the text file git is already tracking it. You need to remove it from git so that it will be untracked, then it will properly ignore it.

```
git rm --cached name.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem like the solution at first glance, but it really is. Git will not ignore any file it is already tracking. Will this help if the file has already been added to the repository?

Comment: Yea it will help if the file is already added to the repo but you'll have to `git add .` and commit so that it gets committed as deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You probably already committed the file so it is tracked. You need to:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Gitignore does not stop you from tracking already tracked files. You need to remove them from your repo.

```
find . -name '*.txt' ¦ xargs git rm
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added that `.txt` file in the staging index before including `.txt` in the `.gitignore` file. To untrack it, you have to
remove that `.txt` file from the staging index. To remove it from staging index but not from working directory, paste the following line:

```
git rm --cached my_file.txt
```

If it does no work then paste:

```
git rm --cached my_file.txt -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible error is to have white space after the `*.txt` line.